# align the list numbers in

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML. here i'm trying to align the numbers in the list to be aligned towards right, but in my output as of now, they are aligned left(going through some forums i came to know that the list nukbers are by default left aligned)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="itemizedlist">
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(i)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(ii)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(iii)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(iv)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(v)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(vi)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(vii)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div class="para"><span class=item-num>(viii)</span> Item desc</div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

in the current output i get the below result.

```
(i) Item desc
(ii) Item desc
(iii) Item desc
(iv) Item desc
(v) Item desc
(vi) Item desc
(vii) Item desc
(viii) Item desc
```

but i want the output like below.

```
   (i) Item desc
  (ii) Item desc
 (iii) Item desc
  (iv) Item desc
   (v) Item desc
  (vi) Item desc
 (vii) Item desc
(viii) Item desc
```

please let me know how can i get this done.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zktz23f5/), also i've attached my CSS there.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a better approach: `<ol type="i"> <!-- li elements --> </ol>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.item-num{
   display:inline-block;
   width:30px; /* make it whatever u want */
   text-align:right;
}
```

this should fix it

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
.item {
 float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think This is  what you want:Check below Fiddle

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zktz23f5/14/)

CSS:

```
  ul.itemizedlist {
       list-style-type: none;
       margin-left: 0.1em;
    }

    ul.itemizedlist li.item {
       list-style: none;
    }
   .item{

       width:100px; 
       text-align:right;
    }

    .itemizedlist li.item div.para span.item-num {
        margin-left: -0.5em;

    text-indent: 0em;
      margin-right: 0em;
    }
```